# esp 32 cam error:Error compiling for board AI Thinker ESP32-CAM

Tags: arduino, esp32, arduino-esp32

i am new to aurdino and esp32 cam .....i got this error

Arduino: 1.8.19 (Linux), Board: "AI Thinker ESP32-CAM, 240MHz (WiFi/BT), QIO, 80MHz"

and my code is just a example code.

> 

```
 Used: /home/sahil/.arduino15/packages/esp32/hardware/esp32/1.0.6/libraries/WiFi
 Not used: /home/sahil/Downloads/arduino-1.8.19/libraries/WiFi
exec: "python": executable file not found in $PATH
Error compiling for board AI Thinker ESP32-CAM.


This report would have more information with
"Show verbose output during compilation"
option enabled in File -> Preferences.
```

i think my board is not of ai thinker
any idea from photo which board is this
[this is my setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8weXF.jpg)
[this is photo of my esp32 cam](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zet8T.jpg)

1)i have tried to install ftdi driver
2)tried to search online for my esp32 cam board driver (or whatever ai thinker is)

Answer (score 0):

You select board ESP32 Wrover Module if that doesn't work you make this Plug gpo0 into gnp

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).